# (Android) If statement makes my activity to crash

Tags: android, if-statement, crash

Today I asked a question on my first app, to find why my app crashes when testing for connections and providing views according to that... The answers were totally inaccurate and useless... But today evening I found out that none of the code in onCreate, **but the setVisibility() method in the If statement caused my activity to crash**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    } 
    Intent cd = getIntent();
    ConnectionDetector cdr = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    Boolean isInternetPresent = cdr.isConnectingToInternet();
    ImageView glss2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.glass2);
    ImageView glss1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glass1);
    if (isInternetPresent) {
        glss1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        glss2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
       glss1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       glss2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

The whole code works like a charm without these setVisibility methods, but i just want something to control the visibility of two ImageViews in an if statement... Is there a solution? If not possible, are there alternatives to control visibility of an ImageView inside java code?
here's the logcat:

```
05-21 11:05:38.462: E/filePathInTheme(23435): fallback to res
05-21 11:05:38.482: E/filePathInTheme(23435): fallback to res
05-21 11:05:38.652: E/filePathInTheme(23435): fallback to res
05-21 11:05:38.802: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(23435): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-21 11:05:38.812: D/memalloc(23435): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x50c32000 size:11960320 offset:10485760 fd:54
05-21 11:05:39.122: D/memalloc(23435): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51a3b000 size:13434880 offset:11960320 fd:57
05-21 11:05:41.542: E/filePathInTheme(23435): fallback to res
05-21 11:05:41.572: W/dalvikvm(23435): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a659f0)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lemonaade.watchr/com.lemonaade.watchr.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1961)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1152)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4450)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at com.lemonaade.watchr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1925)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    ... 11 more
```

Ton of thanks :)

Comment: Stacktrace (Logcat output) please

Comment: Post your complete messages displayed in logCat, this "05-20 21:11:05.412: E/filePathInTheme(19298): fallback to re", has no meaning of an Exception.

Comment: I was initially confused on how to export the file, now i've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I also had. It seems that `Boolean` has to be lowercase: `boolean` to work properly.

Comment: yeah, boolean had to be all lowercase, I changed it, but there's still crashing

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Primitive Variables like `boolean` type not `Boolean` object.

```
 Boolean isInternetPresent = cdr.isConnectingToInternet(); //INCORRECT!
 boolean isInternetPresent = cdr.isConnectingToInternet(); //CORRECT =)!
```

And i think this is the same problem of a lot of people, `PlaceholderFragment()` must have a layout that contains

```
 ImageView glss2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.glass2);
 ImageView glss1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glass1);
```

and not `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

isInternetPresent is maybe null...or the imageviews. Are they correctly on activity_main layout? Are you sure the ids of imageviews correct? Insert logcat message, it may help us.

Comment: actually the IMGs are in fragment_main... but they still compile correctly without the visiblity thing right?